# how to implement a webview by python on windows

Tags: python, windows, webview

pywebview using IE engine on windows7, which is terrible! It can not load any modern website. Is there exists any alternative package I can use to implement a webview by python on windows?

Answer (score 1):

It is my fault! You can specify **cef** for **pywebview** ! This will use chrome engine for my python project.

```py
import webview
webview.config.gui = 'cef'
```